# Visual Studio code coloring - static const variables

Tags: visual-studio

I was wondering if there is a way in a visual studio (*default or via plugin*)  to assign a specific text color to **static const** type of variable.

*Example where bold text is special color:*

---

int test = 0;

bool isFinished = false;

static const int **variable** = 0;

---

I know this can be done for constants, numbers, method etc. but not sure about **static const** combination.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Code just came up with this functionality for TypeScript and JavaScript. Their documentation can be found here: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide#theming

I actually found your post because I wanted to turn off const different coloring in TypeScript.

To restore the color in Default Dark+ to the previous color, use this code in your "settings.json" (Preferences: Open Settings (JSON))

```
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Default Dark+]": {
        "rules": {
            "variable.readonly": {
                "foreground": "#9CDCFE"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Based on your exact requirement. It might be possible in your language to do something like `[variable.readonly.static]` when your language will be supported.

More info also here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/semantic-tokens-sample